# D 2.0: Class Arguments and Declaration Definitions with "new"?

Tags: syntax, expression, d

I just took a look at the Expressions grammar for D 2.0 ([*NewExpression*](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/expression.html#NewExpression)) and something caught my attention:

> NewExpression:
>
> ```
> NewArguments ClassArguments BaseClasslistopt { DeclDefs }
> ```
>
> ClassArguments:
>
> ```
> class ( ArgumentList )
>
> class ( )
>
> class
> ```

What exactly are these *ClassArguments* and *DeclDefs*? Is there an example somewhere that demonstrates their use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*ClassArguments* is the keyword `class` followed by the constructor arguments. *DeclDefs* are the declarations inside the class.

---

This syntax is to create an instance of an [anonymous nested class](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/class.html#anonymous), e.g.

```cs
import std.stdio;

void main() {
  class K {
    this() { writeln("K.__ctor"); }
  }

  auto f = new class (1, "4", 7.0) K {
    this(int a, string b, double c) {
      super();
      writefln("anon.__ctor: %s %s %s", a, b, c);
    }
  };
}
```

(See http://ideone.com/cA1qo.)

The above can be rewritten into the less obscure form

```cs
import std.stdio;

void main() {
  class K {
    this() { writeln("K.__ctor"); }
  }

  class AnonymousClass : K {
    this(int a, string b, double c) {
      super();
      writefln("anon.__ctor: %s %s %s", a, b, c);
    }
  }
  auto f = new AnonymousClass(1, "4", 7.0);
}
```

Comment: WHOA that is very interesting... might I ask where you found this? I looked all over the D site but couldn't find it!